# Filter on Laravel 5.4 (How it's work?)

Tags: php, laravel, filter, onclick, laravel-5.4

i have code with laravel 5.4
i wanna show data from database with filter date...
how it's work? can help me?
[view.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iiue.jpg)
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwIjJ.jpg)

and this's my code in view.blade.php

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><strong>No</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong>Nama</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong>Alamat</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong>Lokasi</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong>Tanaman</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong>Jumlah Panen</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong>Luas Lahan</strong></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($hasil as $key => $data)
                                    <tr>    
                                        <th>{{$no++}}</th>
                                        <th>{{$data->nama_user}}</th>
                                        <th>{{$data->alamat}}</th>
                                        <th>{{$data->id_lokasi}}</th>
                                        <th>{{$data->nama_tanaman}}</th>
                                        <th>{{$data->jumlah_panen}}</th>
                                        <th>{{$data->luas_lahan_panen}} HA</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Filter</h3>
                    <p>Pilih Tanggal : {!! Form::input('month', 'published_at', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</p>
                    <button name="filter" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="filter" onclick="filter">Pilih Tanggal</button>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this's the code from web.php (route)

```
Route::get('laporhasil', function () {

$hasil = DB::select("SELECT `tbl_user`.`nama_user`, `tbl_user`.`alamat`, `tbl_lapor_hasil`.`id_lokasi`, `tbl_tanaman`.`nama_tanaman`, `tbl_lapor_hasil`.`luas_lahan_panen`,`tbl_lapor_hasil`.`jumlah_panen`FROM `tbl_lapor_hasil` INNER JOIN `tbl_user` ON `tbl_lapor_hasil`.`id_user` = `tbl_user`.`id_user` INNER JOIN `tbl_tanaman` ON `tbl_lapor_hasil`.`id_tanaman` = `tbl_tanaman`.`id_tanaman`");
$no = 1;

return view('laporhasil', ['hasil' => $hasil], ['no' => $no]);
```

});

Comment: Use the query builder and there is a method called `whereDate` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries.

Comment: Any special reason for using Query Builder Instead Eloquent ?

Comment: @Qazi eloquent uses a builder instance to perform queries and he is not using a model on his closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all data which are created today then you then you can follow this code snippet-

```
$data = Modelname::whereDate('created_at','=',\Carbon\Carbon::now())->get();
//Assuming you have a date field named `created_at`
```

If you want to get data by specific day then -

```
$data = Modelname::whereDay('created_at','=',$day)->get();
```

Same way you can get data by month or year.

```
$data = Modelname::whereMonth('created_at','=',$month)->get();
$data = Modelname::whereYear('created_at','=',$year)->get();
```

The `$day, $month, $year` represents day, month and year value respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Make a filter form with get method and same route in the action as the route view.blade.php.

i.e. if your route of view.blade.php is `my-data` then make a filter form like

```
    <form action="{{route('my-data')}}" method="GET">
         <input type="text" name="date" class="some-class" />
         <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </form>
```

And the method of the route `my-data` like -

```
public function myData(Request $request){

      $model = new Mymodel(); // This is you model name of the corresponding table

      if(!empty($request->date)){
           $model = $model->whereDate('date','=', $request->date);
      }
      if(empty($request->date)){
           $result = Mymodel::all();
      }else{
           $result = $model->get();
      }
      return view('view', compact('result'));
}
```

This method checks if the request has date field and it's value or not. If it finds date field then fetch the data from `Mymodel`. Careful about not to use `->get()`. Finally check if the request has no date field then request all the data you want to fetch from `Mymodel` otherwise get the filtered data to your view.